# With bnd, is it possible to have define a bundle just in the state resolved, not started?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, bnd, bndtools

I wan't to delay the start of some bundles, but of course I want to resolve them. I want to start the bundles by myself at a later point in time.

Is this possible at all through bnd?

My use case is basically that I don't want to start the gogo shell when the container is up, but do that later when I decide to do that.

Comment: Are you talking about when running a bndrun file from the IDE, or an exported app from that bndrun?

Comment: both actually, I want to make the decision to start the console depending on some parameter from the command line

Comment: Maybe @PeterKriens can answer this.

Comment: I would normally say use start levels but AFAIK bnd does not provide a way to define those.